# open my website in iframe or modal pop up instead of redirecting to my page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Currently I have a controller that returns a view, so to integrate with my website the other website has to post the form to my above mentioned controller that returns the view.

Now what I want is to provide some script to one who wants to integrate with my website, such that on posting form to my controller they dont redirect to my page, rather my webpage opens on their page itself in a modal popup or an iframe.

Comment: This sounds like you want to make an API. API's are a way for websites to talk to one another and share information. So you would make an API and the other website would use the api to post data and get a return in json which it could then parse and display.

Comment: API controllers can be added in your c# mvc application quite easily. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio